# Change the numbering list style in Microsoft Word to custom ordinals

Tags: microsoft-word

How may I change the numbering list style to something other than the built-in ordinal style (First, Second, Third, ...) in Microsoft Word 2010, for example to something like zuerst, zweite, dritte, ... in German, or to change the ordinals in my custom way in Kurdish as the following:
یک instead of the "First",
and دوو instead of the "Second",
and سه instead of the "Third" and likewise for the other ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the ordinals for some languages. Let's say you have already numbered a list using the English ordinals. Then, to change a particular bllet to use German, you need to select its paragraph mark and mark the language as German (e.g. select the paragraph mark, click the language "button" in the status bar at the bottom of the Word window, and select German (Germany). In that case, I think First is "Erste." rather than "Zuerst."

That only seems to work for some languages. It isn't obvious to me why, for example, it does not work for others (e.g. Arabic). It could be one of those things that depends on the installation language or the "primary editing language" - I just don't know. But as far as I know, Kurdish isn't supported at all, so you could not use that approach.

For unsupported languages I think you would have to implement your own numbering, perhaps using field codes. There are various ways you could consider doing that. For example, suppose you wanted your numbering to go up to 100. You could then insert { SET } fields like this:

`{ SET Kurdish1 "the kurdish text for 'first' }{ SET Kurdish2 "the kurdish text for 'second' }` ...and so on.

Then, to insert the appropriate text for each bullet, you could use the nested field code.

```
{ REF "Kurdish{ SEQ bullet }" }
```

All the { } have to be the special field code brace pairs that you can insert on Windows Word using ctrl-F9. You may also have to work a bit harder to get this to work for right-to-left scripts. Unlike the built-in paragraph numbering, you have to select these fields and update them using F9 when, for example, you insert or delete a bullet.

`{ SET }` fields can easily be damaged by the user. Instead you could put the ordinals into Custom Document Properties called Kurdish1, Kurdish2 etc., and use

```
{ DOCPROPERTY "Kurdish{ SEQ bullet }" }
```

My personal preference would be to use VBA to put the texts into Document Variables that you can only see using programming or by looking inside the .docx, e.g.

Activedocument.Variables("Kurdish1").Value = "the kurdish word for 'First'"
etc.

Then use:

```
{ DOCVARIABLE "Kurdish{ SEQ bullet }" }
```